# Prove Borel-Cantelli's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, proof-verification, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let
>   $(A_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of events in $\mathcal{F}$. Prove that
>   $\mathbb {P}(\limsup_{n \geq 1} A_n) = 0$ if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty
>  \mathbb{P}(A_i)$ converges.

**My attempt**:

$$0 \leq\mathbb {P}(\limsup_{n \geq 1} A_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb {P}(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k)\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=n}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_k) = 0$$

The last equality needs some work. The other (in)equalities are basic properties.

Let $\sum_{i=1}^\infty
 \mathbb{P}(A_i):= S$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $n_0$ such that $n \geq n_0$ implies that $|S - \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_i)| < \epsilon$. Then, if $n \geq n_0+1$, it follows that $|\sum_{k=n}^\infty \mathbb{P}({A_k})| = |\sum_{k=1}^ \infty\mathbb{P}(A_k) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\mathbb{P}(A_k)| = |S - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\mathbb{P}(A_k)| < \epsilon$. This proves the desired equality. Is this correct?

Comment: You attempt looks good to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last equality is an elementary result from calculus:
Set $a: = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb P (A_i)$. Then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=n}^\infty \Bbb P (A_i) = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb P (A_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \Bbb P (A_i) =a -\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \Bbb P (A_i) = a-a =0.
$$

Comment: Thanks. This is essentially what happens in the epsilon proof.

Comment: Yeah, that's true :)

Comment: I did not look at it this way though, so your answer was enlightening :) Guess I should focus less on formal real analysis haha